# Java XML: ClassCastException DeferredTextImpl

Tags: java, xml, parsing, nodelist

Here is my code:

```
// get the factory
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

try {

    // Using factory get an instance of document builder
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

// parse using builder to get DOM representation of the XML file
    dom = db.parse(file);

} catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
    pce.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXException se) {
    se.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}

NodeList n1 = dom.getChildNodes();
Element e1 = (Element) n1.item(0);

System.out.println(n1.getLength());
System.out.println(e1.getNodeName());

NodeList n2 = n1.item(0).getChildNodes();
Element e2 = (Element) n2.item(0);   //Line 61

System.out.println(n2.getLength());
System.out.println(e2.getNodeName());
```

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<test-fw:test
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:test-fw="http://simitar/test-fw"> 

<rule-tree>
<rule class="matchlines">
<property name="contiguous"> true</property>
<property name="inOrder">false</property>
<property name="exact">false</property>
<property name="lines">modelInstantiated</property>
</rule>
<rule class="matchlines">
<property name="contiguous"> true</property>
<property name="inOrder">true</property>
<property name="exact">false</property>
<property name="lines">InitEvent</property>
</rule>
</rule-tree>

</test-fw:test>
```

Here is my output:

```
1
test-fw:test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredTextImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element
    at testpack.Main.run(Main.java:61)
    at testpack.Main.main(Main.java:86)
```

I keep getting this error. I am completely lost. I have no idea what to do. I want to able to have one node, and be able to grab all it's children and put them into an array or list, so I can iterate through them.

Here are all my imports:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
```

I've had the hardest time trying to get this Java to parse this XML file.

Comment: please post your imports, think you missed something there.

Comment: It would be helpful if you pointed out which line in your snippet is line 61.

Comment: Plus, the title is wrong. This is not a parsing error, but a class cast exception.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
NodeList n1 = dom.getChildNodes();
Element e1 = (Element) n1.item(0);
```

The node is not an `Element`, but a `Node`.

Try this:

```
Node no1 = (Node) n1.item(0);
```

Nodes can be text nodes or elements, for example. In particular,

```
<root>
<element/>
</root>
```

is **4** nodes. A `root` *element*, a *text node* containing `\n`, the `element` *element* and another *text node* containing `\n`.

Comment: I change the Elements to Nodes, but its still gives me the wrong answer. Instead, of the Exceptions, it will output this: 1\ntest-fw:test\n3\n#text

Comment: you are aware that newlines will produce text nodes inbetween of your elements? Your first node is the **newline** inbetween of `<rule-tree>` and `<rule>`. Which is a string of length 1, containing `\n`.

Comment: So, I'm guessing that when the #text outputs, that is the \n?

Comment: Yes, it is. When handling XML, make sure to program defensively against additional text nodes, and additional white space. In many cases, you may want to treat a string such as `an\n example` the same way as `an example`, to allow the user to insert arbitrary newlines to make the XML more readable. Web browsers for example do this.

Comment: What would these two lines do?     dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    dbf.setValidating(dtdValidate || xsdValidate);

Comment: Enable namespace awareness and validation. Grab a random XML book for what namespaces are (tags and attributes starting with `something:` use namespaces), and validation, well, will report errors when the file is not valid XML.

Comment: Is there an easy way to remove those #test from the NodeList?

Answer (score 4):

Notice that `NodeList.item`returns a `Node` object, which can but does not have to be an `Element`.

In your case, the method returns a [`DeferredTextImpl`](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xerces2/org/apache/xerces/dom/DeferredTextImpl.html) instance, which represents a text node. This class implements the [`DeferredNode`](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xerces2/org/apache/xerces/dom/DeferredNode.html) interface, which is, in turn, a subinterface of [`Node`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html).

In order to process the `Node` instances, you'll have to make sure you can safely perform the cast. The `Node` interface provides methods that allow you to check the type of a node [`getNodeType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getNodeType%28%29), which returns a `short` value that you can compare to the constants defined in the very same interface like [`ELEMENT_NODE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#ELEMENT_NODE)

Comment: What would these two lines do?     dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    dbf.setValidating(dtdValidate || xsdValidate);

Comment: The first one (`dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);`) makes the parser take [XML namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) into consideration. To put it simply, namespaces allow you to differentiate elements with the same names and different definitions. A `cat` element can mean totally different things in a document describing animals and in a document about shell commands. Thanks to namespaces, everyone can define their own elements, structure and name them as they please.

Comment: As for the second one (`dbf.setValidating(dtdValidate || xsdValidate);` ), it's possible to embed [Document Type Definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition) in XML documents. If such definition is provided, it's possible to not only check if a document is [well formed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element) but also follows a specific schema. Setting the `validating` property to `true` makes the parser check for compliance with an embedded DTD (if present) and not only for well-formedness.

Answer (score 4):

Just need to check the `Node`is an `Element` or not . Following is the way to convert `Node` into `Element`.

```
NodeList nodes = root.getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    if(nodes.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
         Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
         ............................
    }
}
```